# <ion-img> does not display the base64 string image

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am taking a picture from a camera in my ionic app using capacitor plugin and showing it on my html.
The picture is not displayed in the browser

```
<ion-img
        role="button"
        class="image"
        (click)="onPickImage()"
         [src]="selectedImage"
       
></ion-img>
```

Since the above didn't work I tried to put the base64 string directly to . even that did not work. Can someone kindly point out what's wrong here

```
<ion-img
        role="button"
        class="image"
        (click)="onPickImage()"
         src=""iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg <the remaining part of base64 string of the image>"
       
></ion-img>
```

I get the below displayed in the browser
[image]

Comment: Does your `selectedImage` value start with `data:image/png;base64,`?

Comment: No it does not start like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I added it it worked. The tutorial I was following had no mention about it.

Comment: yes, though it's not directly ionic. Thanks mate